# Get desired output using sql considering high performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table users:

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `pin` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'India',
  `pic` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gst_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utype` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `creating_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
);
```

I get multiple set ids using some criteria from the above table e.g.

```
id-(1,2) using criteria1
id-(1,3) using criteria2
id-(3,5) using criteria3
```

now I want to display the name, city and CriteriaApplicable in a single query such that I will get the unique row

desired output like:

```
 id            name     criteriaApplicable
 1             Rahul    criteria1, criteria2
 2             Tarun    criteria2
 3             Rishabh  criteria2,criteria3
 5             Krishna  criteria3
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @JiteshAgrawal . . . The code is clearly MySQL so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression and `concat_ws()` to combine them:

```
select id,
       concat_ws(',',
                  (case when criteria_1 then 'criteria_1' end),
                  (case when criteria_2 then 'criteria_2' end),
                  (case when criteria_3 then 'criteria_3' end)
                ) as criteriaApplicable
from users u
having criteriaApplicable <> '';
```

This uses an extension of MySQL that allows the use of column aliases for filtering in the `HAVING` clause.